# time complexity for basic loop algorithm

Tags: python, time-complexity

```
n = 10 # just as an example, n can be anything
sum = 0
for var in range(n):
  sum+=1

print(sum)
```

so, im looking at this code and is supposed to be 3n + 2
so where this n come from?

- 1n ==> n = 10
- 2n ==> var
- 3n ==> range(n)

I want someone who is good at this to confirm this...

Answer (score 0):

time complexity of a code indicates the number of times a single operation is done to do something with that code.
In this case the loop will run n times (whatever number n is). Thus the time complexity of this code is O(n).